# Qt Windows 32 bit deployment issues

Tags: qt, deployment

I'm trying to deploy QT to a 32 bit Windows but when I try to run the file on other computers (I tried on Windows 10) I get an error:

```
The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b)
```

To make the deploy I used this:

```
C:\Qt\5.9.1\ msvc2015\bin\windeployqt.exe -release -compiler-runtime my_program.exe
```

This is a picture of the output (partially) of dependency walker

[image]

[image]

It is important to note that I also use additional libraries (`OpenSSL` and `Boost`) in my software here is my PRO file:

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2017-10-01T05:52:49
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui multimedia multimediawidgets

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = MypROGRAM
TEMPLATE = app

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any feature of Qt which as been marked as deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if you use deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0


SOURCES += \
        main.cpp \
        mainwindow.cpp \

HEADERS += \
        mainwindow.h \

FORMS += \
        mainwindow.ui

RESOURCES += \
    my_icones.qrc


#openssl
win32 {
INCLUDEPATH += c:/OpenSSL-Win32/include

# for openssl - I added these 2 lines
LIBS += -LC:\OpenSSL-Win32\lib -llibeay32
}


RESOURCES += \
    my_icones.qrc



# add boost support
INCLUDEPATH += C:/boost_1_65_1/
LIBS += "-LC:/boost_1_65_1/lib/"

# special libs
LIBS += Advapi32.lib
LIBS += User32.lib
LIBS += Mpr.lib
LIBS += Shlwapi.lib
LIBS += ntdll.lib
```

I would be very happy if any of you could help
Thanks.

Comment: windeployqt does most likley not deploy openssl/boost. Check the folder of your deployed program and check if you can find the libraries. (Or did you install the dlls to the system directories?)

Comment: i don't see this libraries in the deploy folder , how can i fix it? how can i make windeployqt to also deploy them? (i didn't install those libs on my computer - i added them menually)

Comment: Not via windeployqt. Create a script (batch/pyhton/perl/...) or a custom qmake target that runs windeployqt as well as copying all the other required libraries. Windeployqt is for the Qt parts only.

Comment: `windeployqt` also clears `Qt5Core.dll` from hardcoded installation path. You should use it. More info there: http://www.tripleboot.org/?p=536